# route computer music directly to sound card with or without qjack

Tags: vlc, youtube, soundcard

I would like to be able to transmit the music played from youtube or vlc or any other software .. directly to the sound card which in turn is connected to the speakers .. so that I can listen to music from youtube at any time and if I want to record with music mics can do that too without having problems... Currently I can't connect youtube to qjack and in turn route it to the sound card, can anyone help me? I use Ubuntu Studio 23.04 Lunar Lobster version

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].